# How to update a column with corresponding values from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-update

How to update the Associate column so that every item in it will be replaced by their corresponding ID?

| ID | Client | Associate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fun Biz | Circus |
| 2 | Fudge Factory | Sweets Co. |
| 3 | Circus |  |
| 4 | Sweets Co. | Fun Biz |

So that the result would be...

| ID | Client | Associate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fun Biz | 3 |
| 2 | Fudge Factory | 4 |
| 3 | Circus |  |
| 4 | Sweets Co. | 1 |

Comment: which database are you using? a self join will be enough

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
UPDATE yourtable a
SET a.Associate = (
  SELECT b.ID
  FROM yourtable b
  WHERE b.Client = a.Associate
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There's just red underline because of "mytable a", although I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: You didn't say what the name of your table was, so I just called it 'yourtable'. Replace that with the table's name.

Comment: Yes, I got that but still I get this error message: "Error while executing SQL query on database 'clientdb': near "a": syntax error"

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The editor I'm using is SQLiteStudio, thus I believe it's SQL database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQLite I'm afraid but I've had a look online, does this work?

`UPDATE yourtable AS a SET Associate = (SELECT b.ID FROM yourtable b WHERE b.Client = a.Associate)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked... although curiously the query had red underline again all the way starting from the word "as". But anyway this solved my problem!